# When modifying SimpleHtmlSanitizer.java, how to deal with <a href=> (Gwt)?

Tags: gwt

You know that SimpleHtmlSanitizer.java only accepts the following markup ("b", "em", "i", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "hr", "ul", "ol", "li"). It is good but I want "u", "sub", "a href=" & don't want "hr", "ul", "ol", "li". So I need to modify this class.

Now look at the SimpleHtmlSanitizer.java (https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SimpleHtmlSanitizer.java?r=8653) & look at this line in that class:

```
Arrays.asList("b", "em", "i", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "hr", "ul", "ol", "li"));
```

You can guess that we can put our wished list into that line of code right. So I modify it to:

```
Arrays.asList("b","i", "u", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4","a href="));
```

Every tag in that list works fine except the "a href=". For example, when i put the string `Test <a href="car.com"><hr>hello</a>` it didn't show correct output. The correct output should have string `<hr>hello` in hyperlink.

So how to modify SimpleHtmlSanitizer in the case of`<a href=`

Comment: A consideration to make - href can be used in an unsafe way, so you must sanitize the url. Try `<a href="javascript:alert(1)">test</a>` - if you see an alert popup, you have not correctly prevented arbitrary (and unsafe!) JavaScript from being run in your app. This is just one example, there are other cases, look into UriUtils for URL sanitization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `SimpleHtmlSanitizer` sanitizes *attribute-free* tags, which `<a href="">` is not. Hence you have to poke into the [`simpleSanitize()`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SimpleHtmlSanitizer.java#77) method to allow that.
But do note that it wasn't mentioned for that so you'd probably use another algorithm in it, and it smells like not being safe.

Comment: Thax you Colin & Andrea, i didn't know that href is not safe.